# How do I add a strawberry swirl to my cheesecake without cracks and craters?

Tags: baking

I have recently experimented with adding a strawberry swirl to my cheesecake. I am using homemade strawberry jam to swirl in the flavor. Everything has gone great with it other than I get a bunch of big red craters! What am I doing wrong? How do I make a strawberry swirl without having the cheesecake full of the cracks and craters?

[image: Cheesecake Craters!]

Here is a second picture after it cools a bit. Some of the crack come back together and others are still wide open.
[image: Second picture after it cold a bit]

Edit:

I was using this recipe and then added my own swirl: https://sugarspunrun.com/best-cheesecake-recipe/

Comment: Have you considered using a no bake cheesecake? Much easier to swirl as above! Please post the recipe of your bake in your question

Comment: I had considered it but everyone loves this recipe so much that I thought I'd try adding a swirl to it. It dose still taste amazing, even with the craters! If the answer is that I can't prevent the craters when baking one I'll have to try a no bake next time! Just thought I'd see if I can fix this recipe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is advice I found online for adding a swirl into a similar [cheesecake recipe](https://www.thespruceeats.com/raspberry-swirl-cheesecake-recipe-101325):

> Put the jam and lemon juice in a small saucepan and heat over low heat, stirring often, until melted and smooth. Drizzle 1/4 of the jam mixture in stripes over the batter. Spoon the remaining batter over the jam, then drizzle with the remaining jam. Swirl gently with a thin knife to marbleize the batter slightly.

Comment: Made roughly this: strawberries, sugar, and orange juice (no lemon juice on hand) over medium heat. Cool then swirl. Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 7):

I'd mix a small amount of your cheesecake batter with your strawberry component to help with it's bake stability. Try that and swirl that in. Hope that helps.

Comment: This worked relatively well but I saved too much batter and lost most of the coloring. I will try it again next time and accept this as the answer if I get similar results.